# C# Quartz alert when trigger end date is passed

Tags: c#, triggers, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have some jobs that I save their details in a database, and I want to inform the database that a job trigger end date has passed and that the schedule is "completed". 
I have read about TriggerListener and it has a completed event, but it's firing every time the job is done executing, and this is not what I'm trying to do. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement ISchedulerListener and listen for TriggerFinalized event that informs that the given trigger will never fire again according to its schedule.

Comment: Hi @Marko Lahma Could u give some example ?